# Django. Returning a random small list from a larger Query

Tags: python, django, random

I am completely lost here since this works with a normal list but not with a djnago queryset.

I want to return a list with 3 objects selected at random from a django query.

I tried this:

```
def get_small_list():

    indexes = range(7)
    random.shuffle(indexes)
    query_objects = Posts.objects.filter(...)[:7]
    small_list = []
    for i in range(3):
        index = indexes.pop()
        post = query_objects[index]
        small_list.append(post)

    return small_list
```

... It doesn't work. Sometimes, the small_list has repeated values. I don't know why.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried `random.sample(query_objects, 3)`?

Comment: Or `query_objects.order_by('?')[:3]` ?

Comment: random.sample worked. Thanks @jonrsharpe. If you post it as an answer, I'll accept it. order_by('?') is another option but it a really expensive query in terms of time and memory consumption.

Comment: You should benchmark the both methods. The problem with `random.sample` is that the whole query set is loaded in memory, which is for sure very expensive in terms of time and memory if the queryset is big. Instead the `'?'` "may" be expensive, so I guess some RDBMs handle it very well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than picking one random item at a time, you can use [`random.sample`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.sample) to do it in one step:

```
random.sample(query_objects, 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

As official documentation says: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#order-by-fields

> To order randomly, use "?", like so:
>
> Entry.objects.order_by('?')